# Unable to boot from the Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8 and Ubuntu 16.04 operating systems

Tags: disk-utility, partition, snow-leopard

My early 2008 MacBook runs on a dual boot of Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8 and Ubuntu 16.04. I deleted some partitions, so I am unable to boot either OS X or on Ubuntu. I tried a repair by using installation DVD Disk Utility and Time Machine, but both are unable to find the target volume.

Comment: Have you booted from the recovery partition and tried the reformat the hard drive first?

Comment: I booted from the disk utility install disk. In snow leopard there is no recovery partition. The problem is the hard drive is not visible any more, I think I need  something like refinder , a booting app, but probably I deleted this partition on my hard drive.

Comment: Boot from the installation DVD. Open a Terminal application window and enter the command `gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0`. Post the results to your question. Also, do you have a Time Machine backup of the OS X partition?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The command you gave me  resulted in:" gpt show: unable to  open device dev/, no such  file or directory. gpt show; disk0: suspicious MBR at sector 0"

Comment: After many trials and errors I managed to boot from the installation disk. So I could restore my old 10.6. 8. system.